# Why the if statement from the java code is jumped even if the "module" and "sModule" are equal

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sorting, if-statement

I try to select only the files with same module to be displayed on the
list view from an sql table. If I'm using if (module == smodule) the app is ok but the if statement is jumped, using if (module.equals(smodule)) the app is crasing.

Thanks  @Nambari problem is that I had a null for the value of module in the database.

Thanks @Buhake Sindi for the suggestion 'Instantiate it like String module = ""'

Java code.................:

```
private void getFiles() {                               //getting data from the SQL database
    String[] columns = {"id", "file", "module", "date", "note"};
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query("files", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    files.clear();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String module = cursor.getString(2);
        String smodule = "Alllllll";
        Log.v("test", smodule+" "+module+" <-if m=sm getting sql data /not if");
        if (module.equals(smodule)){
             String file = cursor.getString(1);
             files.add(file);
             Log.v("test", file+" "+files+" <-if m=sm getting sql data/if");
        }
    cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    helper.close();
```

Logcat:

```
Alllllll null <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
Alllllll null <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
Alllllll null <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
Alllllll null <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
Alllllll Alllllll <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
Alllllll Alllllll <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
Alllllll Alllllll <-if m=sm getting sql data not/if
```

Error log after replacing == with .equals():

```
03-28 14:31:03.985: E/SpannableStringBuilder(25898): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 14:31:03.985: E/SpannableStringBuilder(25898): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 14:31:15.030: D/AbsListView(25898): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-28 14:31:15.085: W/ResourceType(25898): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
03-28 14:31:15.090: W/ResourceType(25898): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
03-28 14:31:15.225: E/SpannableStringBuilder(25898): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 14:31:15.225: E/SpannableStringBuilder(25898): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-28 14:31:28.950: D/AbsListView(26523): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-28 14:31:29.060: D/libEGL(26523): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-28 14:31:29.075: D/libEGL(26523): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-28 14:31:29.080: D/libEGL(26523): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-28 14:31:29.090: D/(26523): Device driver API match
03-28 14:31:29.090: D/(26523): Device driver API version: 10
03-28 14:31:29.090: D/(26523): User space API version: 10 
03-28 14:31:29.090: D/(26523): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
03-28 14:31:29.115: D/OpenGLRenderer(26523): Enabling debug mode 0
03-28 14:31:29.135: W/ResourceType(26523): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
03-28 14:31:29.145: W/ResourceType(26523): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
03-28 14:31:30.780: D/AbsListView(26523): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-28 14:31:30.800: V/test(26523): Alllllll null <-if m=sm getting sql data /not if
03-28 14:31:30.805: D/AndroidRuntime(26523): Shutting down VM
03-28 14:31:30.805: W/dalvikvm(26523): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4189f2a0)
03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cn/com.example.cn.ListView2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (module == smodule){
```

should be

```
  if (module.equals(smodule)){
```

While comparing String/Objects. It is better to use `equals()` than `==`

`==` checks for reference equality. `equals()` checks for object equality.

Comment: It's not only *better*, it's the only (correct) way to compare equality (and not only for Strings)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: agree. But reason why I have better there is, when you compare String literals, == also works.

Comment: if I'm using 
`if (module.equals(smodule)){` 
is crashing the app

Comment: @MV: Without error message, can't predict what is going on. Update question with error stack.

Comment: `==` is **not** guaranteed to work with String literals. You should avoid using that.

Comment: `03-28 14:31:30.800: V/test(26523): Alllllll null <-if m=sm getting sql data /not if`
`03-28 14:31:30.805: D/AndroidRuntime(26523): Shutting down VM`
`03-28 14:31:30.805: W/dalvikvm(26523): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4189f2a0)`
`03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`
`03-28 14:31:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(26523): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cn/com.example.cn.ListView2}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @MV: It seems NullPointerException. Please edit question and update full stack trace over there. Make sure "module" is not null.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not evaluating the **value** of the `String`, instead you are comparing its object reference.

For String value comparison, use the `equals()` method, like so:

```
if (module.equals(smodule)) {
```

---

Seeing that `smodule` is never null and that module can be null, to avoid `NullPointerException` rather do:

```
if (smodule.equals(module)) {
```

Comment: if I'm using 
`if (module.equals(smodule)){`
 is crashing the app.

Comment: then make sure that `module` is **never** null. Instantiate it like `String module = "";`

Answer (score 1):

use module.equals(smodule),

**== vs .equals**

- == -> is a reference comparison ie both objects point to the same memory location
- equals() -> evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects
- it's .equals(...) though (first letter is not capitalized).
- equals will only compare what it is written to compare, no more, no
  less.
- if equals is not overridden, it defaults to ==; that is, it returns
  true if both variables refer to the same object.
- Always remember to override hashCode if you override equals so as not
  to "break the contract".

Answer (score 0):

Please use the .equals method and not == in Java. 
Tons of [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) already here.

Comment: sorry for the typo. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (module == smodule)
```

should be

```
if (module.equals(smodule))
```

`==` compares object references.

`equals()` compares object contents.